# How to output a dictionary to stdout in csv format in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have been looking for ways to outputting a dictionary to standard output in a csv format.

Dictionary has the following format

```
my_dict = {
  "column1": ["row1","row2","row3",...],
  "column2": ["row1","row2","row3",...],
  "column3": ["row1","row2","row3",...]
}
```

I have found solutions for outputting a dictionary to stdout:

[Python: List of dictionaries: How to - nice printout using sys.stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47692114/python-list-of-dictionaries-how-to-nice-printout-using-sys-stdout)

I can always just `sys.stdout` every column and row in a for loop. However, I am not confident about what will happen in the edge cases (which some library will do).

I have also found solutions for outputting a dictionary to csv:
[How do I write a Python dictionary to a csv file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373247/how-do-i-write-a-python-dictionary-to-a-csv-file)

However, these always write the dictionary to a file object instead of stdout.

My question is is there any way of outputting dictionaries to stdout in a csv format (that also handles edge cases such as: row values with `,` and `"` characters which will corrupt a csv file)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use [`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html) for methods that require a [file-like object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object). Also `DictWriter` is not the right tool for this task as it works on a `list` of `dict`s:

```
import csv
from io import StringIO

my_dict = {
  "column1": ["row1", "row2", "row3",],
  "column2": ["row1", "row2", "row3",],
  "column3": ["row1", "row2", "row3",]
}

f = StringIO()
writer = csv.writer(f)
writer.writerow(my_dict.keys())
writer.writerows(zip(*my_dict.values()))

print(f.getvalue())
```

this would print

```
column1,column2,column3
row1,row1,row1
row2,row2,row2
row3,row3,row3
```